# Can't install rust-doc on Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, apt, architecture

I'm running Debian Stretch. According to [the Debian website](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/rust-doc), I should be able to install the package `rust-doc`, yet I can't:

```
wizzwizz4@myLaptop:~$ sudo apt install rust-doc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rust-doc
```

Everything seems to say it doesn't exist. But it does. Do I have to do something special to install `all`-arch packages, or something?

The output of `apt policy` is normal.

Comment: Does `apt update` report any errors?

Comment: @StephenKitt No. Everything's normal, except this. I can install most `all` (dependency) packages fine.

Comment: I just downloaded the package from the Debian website, and am installing it manually. It used a lot of CPU power, though it seems to have worked fine. I've got all the files… which makes it all the more strange that it didn't work properly through the package manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s nothing wrong with your setup, the problem here is the package pool and the web site. The `rust-doc` package was disabled [with the 1.24.1+dfsg1-1~deb9u1](https://tracker.debian.org/news/971133/accepted-rustc-1241dfsg1-1deb9u1-source-amd64-all-into-proposed-updates-stable-new-proposed-updates/) upload:

> Disable `-doc` package, requires packages not found in stretch and
>        docs are available online anyway

As a result the package is no longer included in the indexes and isn’t available from `apt`’s perspective. The package which can still be downloaded [from the web site](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/rust-doc) is the old 1.14.0 release. I’ve [informed](https://lists.debian.org/debian-www/2019/06/msg00087.html) the site team about the discrepancy.

You’ll be able to install the package again normally once Debian 10 is released and you upgrade to that.